# on one page checkout I am facing issue not allow to place order button not working even address also not update

Tags: checkout

```
Uncaught TypeError: items is not a function
    at collection.js:276
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:150)
    at UiClass._updateCollection (collection.js:275)
    at UiClass._insert (collection.js:253)
    at Registry._resolveRequest (registry.js:418)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Registry._updateRequests (registry.js:400)
    at later (underscore.js:821)
```

---

collection.js

```
_updateCollection: function () {
        var _elems = compact(this._elems),
            grouped;

        grouped = _elems.filter(function (elem) {
            return elem.displayArea && _.isString(elem.displayArea);
        });
        grouped = _.groupBy(grouped, 'displayArea');

        _.each(grouped, this.updateRegion, this);

        _.each(this.regions, function (items) {
            var hasObsoleteComponents = items().length && !_.intersection(_elems, items()).length;

            if (hasObsoleteComponents) {
                items.removeAll();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello, I have faced the same issue. Have you resolved this issue?